# any good iphone/ipad photo gallery template

Tags: iphone

i am looking for an easy to use photo gallery however i need to find an easy to implement one that has good and clean functionality.
Any solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[PhotoViewer by Enormego](http://github.com/enormego/PhotoViewer) is good

Answer (score 3):

see [three20](http://three20.info/), the framework, the Facebook app uses.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look [AQGridView](http://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView). It can be used to implement a photo gallery pretty easily.